# Outputting multidimensional json array to table php [multiple values]

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, dereference

I have been at this for the last 9 days and can't for the life of me figure this one out.

It starts by obtaining the JSON array via cURL

```
$result = curl_exec($h);
curl_close($h);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

The output with < pre> and < /pre> is as so:

```
array(1) {
["SE"]=>
array(4) {
    ["errors"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["billwith"]=>
    string(10) "removedInteger"
    ["bill_detail"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["bill_item"]=>
        array(48) {
          [0]=>
          array(7) {
            ["type1identifier_id"]=>
            string(5) "removed coded string "
            ["prod"]=>
            string(15) "removed string"
            ["charge"]=>
            string(4) "1.36"
            ["misc_date"]=>
            string(6) "063014"
            ["misc_date2"]=>
            string(6) "000000"
            ["notes"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["color"]=>
            string(4) "hide"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(7) {
          ["type1identifier_id""]=>
          string(5) "CP024"
          ["prod"]=>
          string(15) "removed string "
          ["charge"]=>
          string(3) ".00"
          ["misc_date"]=>
          string(6) "063014"
          ["misc_date2"]=>
          string(6) "000000"
          ["notes"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["color"]=>
          string(4) "hide"
```

I'm trying to write this information to a table so that it is legible, such as "removed string" is one of the values I wish to write/echo in a  tag, but I can't seem to dereference any of it in this mess.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

One last update, when comparing, it returns false each time, not too sure why, do i need to declare my values first?  Here is the code I'm using:

```
if ($bill_item['charge'] == "attention")
{
    echo '<tr bgcolor="red">';
    echo '<td>';
    echo 'charge amount DOES equal attention';
    echo '</td>';
}
  else
  {
    echo '<tr bgcolor="white">';
    echo '<td>';
    echo 'charge amount does NOT equal attention';
    echo '</td>';
  }
```

Comment: $array["SE"]["bill_detail"]["bill_item"][0] .. [1] etc dosn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the decoded json that turned into array as you normally would:

```
foreach($result['SE']['bill_detail']['bill_item'] as $bill_item) {
    // do what you have to do
    echo $bill_item['prod'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: @user2276056 remember to click that check mark on the left side of this post so that others will know that this question already had its closure/resolution. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: I definitely will!  One last question, my code keeps returning false on this line though :(

Comment: @user2276056 yes its false, definitely :). `$bill_item['charge']` contains float values so comparing it to `== "attention"` doesn't make sense and therefore equates to false