# xPath - from the bottom to top

Tags: php, xpath

Normally, I would use xpath to get a table like so:

```
 foreach($xpath->query('//*[@id="financial"]/div[4]/table/tr') as $row) { 
    echo '<tr>';
      foreach($xpath->query('td[position() > 0]', $row) as $col) {
        echo '<td>'.trim($col->textContent).'</td>'."\n"; }
     echo '</tr>';
```

etc.

The results would display the same as they are in the current table.

However, I would like to display the results from the bottom up.

Any advice?

Comment: Don't make us guess what language you are writing this in.  There are a lot of C-syntax languages.

Comment: Your example implies you are using xpath expressions in a programming language that you have not tagged in your question.  In whatever language you are using, take the return list from the xpath expression and reverse sort it before iterating over it with `foreach`.

Comment: I had a similar situation last year.  Check out my previous post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824157/outputting-multidimensional-json-array-to-table-php-multiple-values?noredirect=1#comment42217360_26824157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't essentially xpath question. You can't control order of elements to be returned using xpath.

Anyway, [`DOMXPath::query` returns `DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php), and you can try to iterate through `DOMNodeList` backward like so :

```
$rows = $xpath->query('//*[@id="financial"]/div[4]/table/tr');
for($i=$rows->length-1; $i>=0; --$i){
    $row = $result->item($i);
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($xpath->query('td', $row) as $col) {
        echo '<td>'.trim($col->textContent).'</td>'."\n"; 
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Related question for future visitor reference : [Reversing order of items in DOMNodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837852/reversing-order-of-items-in-domnodelist)

Side note, `[position() > 0]` is useless. xpath `position()` starts from `1`, so the predicate never evaluates to `false`.